# Convexity of $y\geqslant\frac{1}{x}$ and $xy\geqslant 1$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I would like to ask the convexity of $y\geqslant\frac{1}{x}$ and $xy\geqslant1$.

We know that $y\geqslant\frac{1}{x}$ is convex for $x>0$. But if we transform the inequality into $$xy\geqslant1(x,y>0)$$ or $$1-xy\leqslant0(x,y>0)$$

The inequality becomes nonconvex as the Hessian of the inequality is:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
-1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which has eigenvalues of 1 and -1.

So is it correct that  $y\geqslant\frac{1}{x}$ is convex and $xy\geqslant1$ is nonconvex?

Thank you.

Dylan

Comment: You are confusing the *convexity of sets* and the  *convexity of functions*. Don't. They are two different, but closely related, things.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the convexity of *sets* and the convexity of *functions*.

Don't.

They're closely related, tightly linked, but are by no means identical.

The fundamental link between convex functions and convex sets is this: *a function $f$ is convex if and only if its epigraph $\{(x,y)\,|\,f(x)\leq y\}$ is a convex set.*

So if you have a convex function---and $f(x) = 1/x$ is indeed convex for $x>0$---then its epigraph $\{(x,y)\,|\,x>0,~1/x\leq y\}$ is a convex set.

The important thing to note is that above if-and-only-if relationship *starts with a function*. It doesn't start with a set. You can't necessarily extract a convex function from a convex set.

For instance, there are lots of ways to represent the set, including $\{(x,y)\,|\,x,y\geq 0,~xy\geq 1\}$. But just because this is a convex set *doesn't mean that $f(x,y)=xy$ is a convex function*.

In fact, not every convex set is the epigraph of a convex function; for instance, $C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,\|x\|\leq 1\}$. Is there a convex function in there? Sure is; $f(x)=\|x\|$ is convex. But the set is not the epigraph of $f$.

So again: don't confuse convex sets and convex functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The epigraph is convex $\iff$ the boundary is convex. Notice that they ask you the convexity of $$\left\{(x,y)\mid xy\geq 1\text{ and }y\geq \frac{1}{x}\right\}=\left\{(x,y)\mid x>0\text{ and }y\geq \frac{1}{x}\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that the set is convex. But for the function $1-xy$ on the left hand side, when $x,y>0$ is it nonconvex?

Comment: They don't give you two different curve ! But a set with two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, then your question is how to show that-

$$\left\{(x,y)\mid xy\geq 1\text{ and } x,y> 0 \right\}=\left\{(x,y)\mid x>0\text{ and }y\geq \frac{1}{x}\right\}$$.

**Hint:**

1. The difference between function and its sublevel set.
2. Check $f(x,y)=xy-1$ and $f(x,y)=1-xy$ when $x,y > 0$.
3. Use the defination of convex set.